# Need to count rows mysql that contains specific data in php

Tags: php, mysql

I need a solution. I have a column with multiple data (table `data` type is 'set'), like this:

```
-------
id|data
-------
1 |1,4
2 |2,4,5,12
3 |9,2,4
4 |5,6
5 |2,8
--------
```

I would like to count, how many rows contains 2 and 4?

It is **row[id]=2** and **row[id]=3** so the result is **2**.

I did not find any tutorial for this.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: *"I did not find any tutorial for this."* - Look for "mysql aggregate functions", such as `count()` and `sum()` etc.

Comment: Like count method !

Comment: you really should normalize your db, btw

Comment: you need to restructure your database. but if you are completely stuck with it, then this might be of use https://www.tutorialspoint.com/mysql/mysql-like-clause.htm

Comment: Then look at the [`FIND_IN_SET()`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_find-in-set) MYSQL function.

Comment: mysqli_num_rows() this function count the number of rows of a table

Comment: The sum extent of possible options is as follows: 1. Normalize your data. or 2. Stop using an RDBMS database.

Comment: @Strawberry Its a `SET()` datatype, not your standard database design mistake

Comment: Every number is a service id. I have 12 of them, and the user make choises (with multiple checkboxes) when inserting a row.. thats why it looks like that.. I need count how many times did anybody use either service..

Comment: @RiggsFolly That's a matter of opinion; and not one I share ;-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `FIND_IN_SET()` to process the `SET()` datatype

Like this

```
SELECT count(id) 
FROM tablename
WHERE
    FIND_IN_SET('2', data) AND FIND_IN_SET('4', date);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot RiggsFolly! Thats what I am looking for.